# Why does the Output of a Future need to be Send for the future itself to be send?

Tags: rust, async-await, send, typechecking

I am trying to make `async` cooperative multitasking executor. A feature that I would like to have is to keep some worker-local state for each task. Each worker is pinned to a thread and each thread is pinned to a core.

My idea is for information about the current worker to be returned as part of the future output (see `main` function) in the example:

```rust
#![feature(waker_getters)]

use std::{
    future::Future,
    marker::PhantomData,
    pin::Pin,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    task::{Context, Poll, Waker},
};

type WorkQueue = Mutex<Vec<Waker>>;

/// Info about the current worker. This info should be valid only for
/// the current thead so `WorkerInfo` is absolutely not `Send`.
#[derive(Clone)]
struct WorkerInfo {
    id: usize,
    non_send: PhantomData<*mut ()>,
}
#[derive(Clone)]
struct WorkerLocal {
    /// The worker corresponding to this thread. `WorkerLocal` is not
    /// `Send` because the info in `worker` is only valid for the
    /// current thread.
    worker: WorkerInfo,
    queue: Arc<WorkQueue>,
}

impl WorkerLocal {
    /// Yield control to the executor so that we can be scheduled
    /// later, possibly to another worker. `WorkerLocal` is no longer
    /// valid so it should be consumed. The function returns the
    /// `WorkerLocal` of the thread where it lands on.
    async fn coop_yield(self) -> WorkerLocal {
        WorkerJumper { worker: None, queue: self.queue }.await
    }
}

/// A future for yielding control to the executor and possibly
/// continuing on a different worker later.
struct WorkerJumper {
    worker: Option<WorkerInfo>, // None when asleep
    queue: Arc<WorkQueue>,
}

impl Future for WorkerJumper {
    type Output = WorkerLocal;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        if let Some(ref wid) = self.worker {
            return Poll::Ready(WorkerLocal {
                worker: wid.clone(),
                queue: self.queue.clone(),
            });
        } else {
            // Push into the work queue
            self.queue.lock().unwrap().push(cx.waker().clone());
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

/// Queue some work for the executor to run. the future passed must be
/// `Send` because it may end up in a different thread.
fn spawn<F: Future<Output = ()> + Send>(f: impl FnOnce(WorkerLocal) -> F) {
    todo!()
}

fn main() {
    spawn(|t1| async {
        // here we are on worker 1
        let t2 = t1.coop_yield().await;
        // here we may be on worker 2
    });
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22f16fcb4673274b347de39a280a4fe8)

But the compiler complains that a `Send` async block can't return `!Send` values. Why is that? I would expect that a future is send only if a `!Send` value crosses an `.await`.

Is there a safe way to get around it without making a semantically `!Send` type into `Send`?

Edit: If I interpret the answers correctly, the (part of) the problem seems to be that `WorkerLocal` is crossing an "implicit await" that happens between the function taking ownership of its arguemetns and the contained future actually running.

I have one more tangent that I would like to ask about: I realize that there is no way of having bot `WorkerInfo` be `!Send` and contain it in a future. So I was thinking, let's take an appro `RefCell` approach and delegat the problem to the runtime. Why does replacing `main` and `spawn` in the following way still not work?

```rust
struct UnsafeSend<T>(T);
unsafe impl<T> Send for UnsafeSend<T> {}

/// Queue some work for the executor to run. the future passed must be
/// `Send` because it may end up in a different thread.
fn spawn<F: Future<Output = ()> + Send>(f: impl FnOnce(UnsafeSend<WorkerLocal>) -> F) {
    todo!()
}


fn main() {
    spawn(|t| async {t.0.coop_yield().async;});
}
```

Still refuses to build, even though `t1` does not cross any implicit or explicit `await`s.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay for a future to use `!Send` values *that it temporarily holds* as long as those don't cross an await point. But in this case, the future *owns* a `!Send` value, so it can't be Send. In particular, consider the moment at which the expression

```rust
    async {
        let t2 = t1.coop_yield().await;
    }
```

has been **evaluated** — before the future is polled. (`async` blocks (and `async fn`s) don't execute *any* of the code inside them until the first time they're polled.) This is an `impl Future`, and it currently owns `t1`, which is `!Send`, so it must be `!Send` itself.

So, one thing we can do is change the code so that it uses `t1` immediately without putting it in the future:

```rust
    spawn(|t1| {
        let j = t1.coop_yield();
        async {
            let t2 = j.await;
        }
    });
```

However, that probably doesn't suit your goals. And it doesn't work anyway; `WorkerJumper` isn't `Send` either, because it contains an `Option<WorkerInfo>` which is `!Send`.

In general, the problems you're running into seem to be that you want analysis of `Send`ness that is based on the *states* of various values (e.g. the premise that the `Option` is always `None` when jumping threads). But that's not how the compiler works — a given *type* is either `Send` or not. So you need to make sure that, for each *type* in your system (including the anonymous types of async blocks), the ones that need to be `Send` *never contain* anything `!Send`.

I don't have a solution for your particular design goals, but I hope this explanation helps you understand how to collaborate with the compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand but I can't get it to work even by unsafely relaxing the `!Send` bound. Any ideas about it (see edits to the question).

Comment: @fakedrake [It compiles for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=218ac14abb90d512bb50ce7751d0abd9) -- though this is obviously not a good approach either.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that futures do not do any work unless polled.  If you run the code `async { println!("foo"); }` but never poll the future this expression produces, nothing is printed to the screen.

Now if we look at your code, we can see that `spawn()` requires a function that accepts a `WorkerLocal` and returns a future that implements `Send`.  This is problematic, because the `t1.coop_yield()` call hasn't yet happened, so the future must own `t1` (it captures it by move since `coop_yield()` takes `self`) so that it can make this call later, when it is polled.

This means that before it's even polled, it owns a `WorkerLocal` which isn't `Send`, but the future must be `Send`.  This is the contradiction the compiler is pointing out.

I can't think of a way you can convey this kind of thread-local information in the kind of API you want given the way futures in Rust work; you would need to modify the signature of `Future::poll()` to convey this information.

Comment: Thank you that clarifies it  pretty much. I tried relaxing the requirement of `WorkerLocal` being `!Send` but I still find problems. Any ideas about it?